# How to upload file to telegram and get file_id?

Tags: vb.net, telegram

I want to send big files to specific telegram user using C# or VB.Net code.
Now I'm using [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) and it works great for sending a text message. But when I want to send images or files it returns an error at first line like this:

> "Public member 'UploadFile' on type 'TelegramClient' not found."

Here is my code:

```
Private Async Sub btnSendImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSendImage.Click
    Dim fileResult = CType(Await client.UploadFile(fileName, New StreamReader(filePath)), TLInputFileBig)

    Await client.ConnectAsync()
    Dim result = Await client.GetContactsAsync()

    For Each item In result.users
        If (item.phone = phoneNumber) Then
            Await client.SendUploadedDocument(New TLInputPeerUser() With {.UserId = item.id}, fileResult, "some pics", "application/png", New TLVector(Of TLAbsDocumentAttribute)()) 'mime-type - caption
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

It seems there is no UploadFile method in this library anymore.

Is there any other way to upload a file and get file_id?

*I used c# and VB.Net tag because there is no difference between C# or VB.Net code for me. I can use both but my sample is in VB.Net.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. I put it here to help others.

first, we need to add an Imports:

```
Imports TLSharp.Core.Utils.UploadHelper
```

Then change the code as follows:

```
Private Async Sub btnSendImage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSendImage.Click

    Await client.ConnectAsync()

    Dim fileResult As TLAbsInputFile = Await UploadFile(client, fileName, New StreamReader(filePath))

    Dim result = Await client.GetContactsAsync()

    For Each item In result.users
        If (item.phone = phoneNumber) Then
            Await client.SendUploadedDocument(New TLInputPeerUser() With {.UserId = item.id}, fileResult, "some pics", "application/png", New TLVector(Of TLAbsDocumentAttribute)()) 'mime-type - caption
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
using TLSharp.Core.Utils;
```

at the top of your file. This is necessary since `UploadFile` is an [extension method](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/blob/d769dd3c2f16baf4b6b0d3e4ae67f506ca58d654/TLSharp.Core/Utils/UploadHelper.cs#L32).

Comment: OK, thank you very much. here is my code, I converted it to c#. https://dotnetfiddle.net/w1Edo7

Comment: Where is the `using TLSharp.Core.Utils;`?

Comment: Oh, I was testing it. I changed it when it did not work. now check it again please: https://dotnetfiddle.net/a9TEeu

Comment: That code is not valid C#. I will remove that tag from your post.

Comment: I already told you that I converted my vb.net code. my original code is in vb.net but I can convert the c# code to vb.net or even create a c# project and use it. I just wanted every .net programmer can see and answer my question. Anyway, thank you for your attention.